# nothing was installed-android sdk manager

Tags: android-studio

I have seen other questions asked about this same problem, and the answer that makes the most sense to me was that i had to run it as administrator. But i don't know how to run it as administrator. My problem is that whenever i want to install something for android studio using the sdk manager it says "Done nothing was installed" and the progress log said something about the folder not being able to be created. I have just installed android studio on my laptop and if it is helpful the laptop is windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for delay, I just mean anything that you needed to download, files, even java updates should be stored in the same folder. I haven't used it myself but try this. Open the android Sdk folder right click on sdk manager run as administrator. select update/new install.

Answer (score 1):

If you cant find the sdk manager, sometimes if you have windows 8.1, you could go to all programs from the start menu and the sdk manager will be there. Then you can run as admin. Hopefully this works and when google releases the final version of android studio, they will fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this.
It's probably a network issue. When you open SDK manager , in the top left extreme you will find tools options,then choose options from a drop down. Screenshot below:
[image]

**It gives you a proxy settings option.Enter the HTTP Proxy Server and port number.** It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

While updating through android sdk manager i was also getting this message but as i run the sdk manager from the directory where it is saved as Run As Administrator it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try Tools > Options...> Others > check Force https://...sources to be fetched using http://...

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Talking about **running under admin**

If you are using **xamarin-visual studio**

Try right click visual studio **open your project under adminstrator**

**Click** open android device monitor

**Install** the things you want.

Goodluck

Answer (score -1):

Restart your system.Its worked for me.